# Opencv Error: assertion failled i < 0, in calibrateCamera()

Tags: c++, opencv, transactions, camera-calibration

I am getting following error message

*OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (i < 0) in create, file /tmp/OpenCV-2.4.0/modules/core/src/matrix.cpp, line 1335
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'cv::Exception'
  what():  /tmp/OpenCV-2.4.0/modules/core/src/matrix.cpp:1335: error: (-215) i < 0 in function create*

while running my code:

What will be possible reasons for this error ?

Code:

```
int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
  // some code ...
  Mat rvec, tvec;
  calibrateCamera(obPts, imPts, imSize, cameraMatrix, distortionCoef, rvec, tvec);
}
```

Comment: Can you post the `// some code ..` ?

Comment: are the output variables (camera matrix, dist coeffs, r, t) empty or did you pre-allocate them?

Comment: @Moreira I have updated my code

Comment: did you try to not use initCameraMatrix2D and instead let the algorithm do that?

Comment: @Micka cameraMatrix is found using initCameraMatrix2D(), distCoeff all values set to zero. The matrix r and t just declared before passing to func, also I have added my code in question

Comment: @Micka I was getting same error when cam matrix is not initialized

Comment: Also My object points have x, y and z values but when I am giving different z values: its showing non planar points are not supported, so I am giving z as 0.

Comment: try with an empty distCoeff vector, too. and try different (artificial) obj and img values, too.

Comment: @Micka  am getting same error when I am using emty distCoeff vec; Also I tried with more obj and img values also but error is same

Comment: can you hard-code some few obj and img points to create a compilable working code sample reproducing that error?

Comment: @Micka I have hard coded point values; Now its in compilable and running form without any modification, and generates same error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We need to give `rvec` and `tvec` as `vector<cv::Mat>`

In the sample code `rvec` and `tvec` is of `cv::Mat`